# WPF & XAML: DisplayToolTipPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

**ListBox control** has property `DisplayMemberPath` that specifies what is showed inside **ListBoxItem**(s).

Unfortunately, I miss property `DisplayToolTipPath`. Do you know some simple way how to simulate this situation in **XAML** (I preffer XAML solution to code).

*My attempt is something like this:*

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ??? {Binding ToolTipMemberPath}}" />
      </Style>
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ToolTipMemberPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</Style>
```

With `ToolTipMemberPath` the desired prop on your ListBoxItem Class.

**EDIT**

The easiest solution when `TooltipMemberPath` is a parent property would involve a Converter:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PathToTooltipConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="TooltipMemberPath" 
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CustomListBoxControl:CustomListBox}}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**IMultiValueConverter**

```
public class PathToTooltipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = values[0] as ListBoxItem;
        string tooltipMemberPath = values[1] as string;

        if (tooltipMemberPath == null)
            return null;

        MyListBoxItemClass itemClass = (MyListBoxItemClass)item.DataContext;
        return itemClass.GetType().GetProperty(tooltipMemberPath).GetValue(itemClass, null);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right. My problem is that **ToolTipMemberPath** is part of parent control. I can get **ToolTipMemberPath** by `{Binding TooltipMemberPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CustomListBoxControl:CustomListBox}}}`. How to merge this with your approach, please?

Comment: @David You can use a `Converter`, updated my answer.